# C code from Cubature package

Tags: c, statistics

Can you please help me understand a C code from [Cubature package](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature)?

My specific questions:

1) What is the purpose of the fwrapper function rcubature.c file?

```
void fWrapper(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval) {
    SEXP xx, fx;
    double *rx, *rfx;
    int i;


    PROTECT(xx = allocVector(REALSXP, ndim));
    rx = REAL(xx);
    for (i = 0; i < ndim; ++i) {
        rx[i] = x[i];
    }
    defineVar(install("x"), xx, CUB_common_env);
    PROTECT(fx = eval(f, CUB_common_env));

    rfx = REAL(fx);
    for (i = 0; i < fdim; ++i) {
        fval[i] = rfx[i];
    }
    UNPROTECT(2);
    count++;
}
```

2) What does the `defineVar` call in `fWrapper` do?

Comment: You'd better read the documentation of the library and run Doxygen over the source code to understand relation among the functions. You may want to read this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/faq .

Comment: 1) It looks like (and this is a guess) it evaluates some symbolic function on an array of C doubles (by mapping them into symbolic values that its library can understand, performing the evaluation, and then reading the values back into a C array). 2) I'd guess `defineVar` sticks some variable named 'x' in the symbolic environment, which is defined as a vector of doubles (maybe it's an array, maybe it's a polynomial).